# How can I increase my hard drive space for a kali 1.0.6 linux 32-bit virtual machine

Tags: vmware, kali-linux

How can I increase my hard drive space for a kali 1.0.6 linux 32-bit virtual machine running on a mac using vmWare Fusion. I was in the process of installing several android sdk's and realized my allocated memory was't going to be sufficient and need to add about 10 gb to the virtual disk.

Below is the size / file name -> of the files in my virtual machine folder for Kali

```
2042363904 Kali Linux 1.0.6 32 bit-s001.vmdk 

2114846720 Kali Linux 1.0.6 32 bit-s002.vmdk 

2112356352 Kali Linux 1.0.6 32 bit-s003.vmdk 

2112356352 Kali Linux 1.0.6 32 bit-s004.vmdk 

2110193664 Kali Linux 1.0.6 32 bit-s005.vmdk 

2070478848 Kali Linux 1.0.6 32 bit-s006.vmdk 

2009858048 Kali Linux 1.0.6 32 bit-s007.vmdk 

1433731072 Kali Linux 1.0.6 32 bit-s008.vmdk 

1703608320 Kali Linux 1.0.6 32 bit-s009.vmdk 

1208614912 Kali Linux 1.0.6 32 bit-s010.vmdk 

1397358592 Kali Linux 1.0.6 32 bit-s011.vmdk 

1659174912 Kali Linux 1.0.6 32 bit-s012.vmdk 

24313856 Kali Linux 1.0.6 32 bit-s013.vmdk 

524288 Kali Linux 1.0.6 32 bit-s014.vmdk 

524288 Kali Linux 1.0.6 32 bit-s015.vmdk 

524288 Kali Linux 1.0.6 32 bit-s016.vmdk 

458752 Kali Linux 1.0.6 32 bit-s017.vmdk 

8684 Kali Linux 1.0.6 32 bit.nvram 

719 Kali Linux 1.0.6 32 bit.plist 

1399 Kali Linux 1.0.6 32 bit.vmdk 

91 Kali Linux 1.0.6 32 bit.vmsd 

2834 Kali Linux 1.0.6 32 bit.vmx 

102 Kali Linux 1.0.6 32 bit.vmx.lck 

278 Kali Linux 1.0.6 32 bit.vmxf 

238 appListCache     

136 caches     

304947 vmware-0.log     

257342 vmware-1.log     

318853 vmware-2.log     

306670 vmware.log
```

Comment: Install GParted to a USB and boot the VM into the USB and that should allow you to increase HD space

Comment: Thanks ryekayo, this is exactly what I needed to do. I found this site pretty useful in the walkthrough of this process you start to explain, http://beerpla.net/2007/08/10/how-to-resizegrow-vmware-linux-disks-and-partitions/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resize your virtual HD, I recommended installing GParted to a USB stick and booting the USB to your virtual machine. GParted will allow you to resize the Harddrive as you cannot mount into it and then expect to resize it. The virtual HD will need to be unmounted.